# rsync - incremental file list sent but files not updated on server

Tags: ssh, rsync, remote, scp

I am working with some source files from a desktop computer. The source files compile and run on a remote server.

As there is a significant delay between me and the server, I have decided to use `rsync` to copy the files down to my computer, edit them, and then sync them back up, again using `rsync`.

However there is a problem... `rsync` doesn't update the files when I sync them back up to the server after editing them at my end. The incremental file list is sent, but the file contents are unmodified.

Here is a full output of my bash session which will explain in detail what happens.

- I have some files on my local machine. I edit one of those files, using an editor such as `vim`. The file structure is fairly generic. I have a project root directory called `2016-07-01`, which contains many subfolders and source files. The folder is just named with the date as a method of version control.

(bash)

```
$ rsync -av ./2016-07-01 user@server:./path-to-project/2016-07-01
user@server's password: [enter password] 
sending incremental file list
2016-07-01/subfolder/
2016-07-01/subfolder/main.cpp

sent 2,238 bytes  received 272 bytes  557.78 bytes/sec
total size is 632,957  speedup is 252.17
```

- It looks like main.cpp has been updated, but when I `ssh` into the server and open it with `vim` I see that it is unchanged. Why is this happening?
- I then run the same command again and the following output is produced...

(bash)

```
$ rsync -av ./2016-07-01 user@server:./path-to-project/2016-07-01
user@server's password: [enter password] 
sending incremental file list

sent 1,342 bytes  received 36 bytes  110.24 bytes/sec
total size is 632,957  speedup is 459.33
```

- This time no incremental file list is sent - I am not sure why - it is as if `rsync` thinks it has updated the files already and therefore does nothing when it has not...
- If I check `main.cpp` at my end it has definitely been changed.
- `main.cpp` on the server side is unchanged.

I have also tried using the `-c` flag for checksums rather than date-time-stamps, again the same result is seen.

Comment: You are rsyncing to "user's" ~/path-to-project/2016-07-01. Is that where you are looking when you ssh to the server and open the file?

Comment: @JasonAzze It is not. How can I get the '~' for "user" on the SERVER side?

Answer (score 2):

In short, this is **not** the correct command...

```
$ rsync -av ./2016-07-01 user@server:./path-to-project/2016-07-01
```

This **is** the correct command...

```
$ rsync -av ./2016-07-01 user@server:./path-to-project
```

Note, **no forward slash or directory name for destination** - when these are left off `rsync` will create the directory as required. I think the `/` and `2016-07-01` imply 2 different things should be done. No `/` means create directory. I am not sure what the effect of adding/removing the `2016-07-01` is if the `/` **is** there. Perhaps someone can clarify this.

Also note there are 3 ways of addressing the destination on the remote server.

- Using the above method starting the address with `.`. The rsync command defaults to the users home directory, so this relative path to the home directory works.
- One can also type out the full absolute path from the root directory. For me this is something like `/afs/servername/u/username/rest_of_path_from_home_dir`
- Finally, using the `~` expansion as a shortcut for the above will also work.